# NodeJS MongoDB processing and storing huge amount of text

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a NodeJS Express APP and I am building an endpoint to update Terms&Conditions

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/admin/info/terms/de?version=2
```

However the text I'm trying to store is way too heavy **(text has tabs, single and double quotes and so on)**, and requires a ton of editing in order to be placed in a json body {"terms":"easy text"}. {"terms": "heavy       "text//"" that .  "I dont" wish to""" editööäääÄÄ""}

What's the best way of handling this kind of text? Convert it to binary and then send it?

My endpoint

```
  router.post('/terms/:language', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { language } = req.params;
    const { version } = req.query;
    const { terms } = req.body;
    if (!version) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Field "version" is empty' });
    let info = await PageInfo.findOne({ $and: [{ version }, { language }] });
    if (info) {
      const update = await PageInfo.findOneAndUpdate({ version: { $eq: version } }, {
        $set: {
          version,
          terms,
          language
        }
      }, { new: true });
      return res.status(200).json({ type: 'update', data: update });
    }
    info = await PageInfo.create({
      version,
      terms,
      language,
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ type: 'new', data: info });
  } catch (e) {
    return res.sendStatus(500);
  }
});
```

Comment: If text i huge, it's huge. You can store it compressed -- choosing the algorithm is the best when you can at least guess the nature of the text _a little bit_ -- but it comes at cost of having to compress and decompress all the time. Only you can know if it's worth it because we don't know the details of your app.

Comment: What you should ask yourself is, are you actually experiencing performance issues with the current way you handle the text?

Comment: You can convert it to base64 maybe. Unless the length is also an issue, not just the characters.

Comment: Yeah base64 seems like a good idea, but after converting it, sending POST req with base64 data and converting it back to text I've noticed that half of the text is missing also some characters are gone.. I'm converting to UTF8 format too.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GridFS is what you will want to use.

You can read more about it here: [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/)

If this doesn't solve your issue, based on my experience, these kinds of issues arise when your schema is poorly modeled so you may want to reconsider how you model it.

Comment: My text files do not exceed 16 MB and never will be, not sure if this extra complexity is needed. The problem is with text formatting and handling, when I'm dealing with raw JSON, however I think encoding text would do the trick.